# fixing broken html emitted by tumblr's templating system

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr-themes

In tumblr's theme templating system you use {ReblogButton} to add a reblog button to the html.  It currently is broken; it's using an "a" tag and it has in it

```
class="reblog_button"style="..."
```

In other words, it's missing the space before the word style.  Is there some way with javascript or whatever that I could fix that?

The reblog button is currently styled as a block element and I'm trying to make it inline.

The test tumblr blog is http://rustycwright.tumblr.com/ and my css is inline in the head.

I just added some "or" bars around the like heart, which is a div that I changed to inline and it's working.

IE's dom explorer **does** show the html with a space before the style tag.

More poking around; IE's dom explorer shows a line through my css for a.reblog_button: inline, as does firefox's Inspector. Can someone explain why?  Is it because of the css they've embedded in the tag?

Comment: You don't need it, because lack of space **does not** make this HTML broken. You probably have other problem if your styles doesn't work. Post CSS declarations.

Comment: @dfsq, when I do a view page source with firefox it flags the a tag in red.  The style part is style="display: block;width:20px;height:20px;" and in my css I have a.reblog_button { display: inline; } and it's still on a separate line.

Comment: you can add a `display:block; float:left;` to the div.like_button... and `float:left;` to the reblog_button.

Comment: `The reblog button is currently styled as a block element and I'm trying to make it inline.` In this case you should have `style="display: inline"`.

Comment: @dsfq; I have display:inline in my css at the top of the html in the head.  I can't change the html for the tag and cannot use style=.

Comment: @E.H.B; thanks, that makes it look how I want it to.  But I'm still puzzled as to why I couldn't make it inline with my css.

Comment: @lumpynose because you want the like_button to 'display:inline;' the reblog button. Then when they displayed inline, you stack them to the left side, right?

Comment: Ignoring that it's working now, using floats, why couldn't I make the reblog button's "a" tag display inline by using css in the head?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:block; float:left;` to the **div.like_button** and `float:left;` to the **reblog_button.**

Looks like working on my browser. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I followed your advice and did that and it works; thank you.  But now I'd like to know why my css for making it inline didn't work.

Comment: I gave my ideas up^ there on the comments, I thought in that sense. and you only forgot to `display:inline;` the 2nd child